# Enrolling records (which are created from datafeed) into different workflow stages in advance workflow application, RSA Archer

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have two applications,one simple,one advance workflow application.

I have to import records(with partial data,few fields) from simple application to advance workflow application.
Along with import(creating new records) in advance workflow application, I want them to be enrolled at different stages(nodes) in advance workflow automatically.

How to do this ?

I checked content enrollment options, but did not find any proper options to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an evaluation node that would evaluate the record when it first enters advance workflow and then direct that record to the proper location (node) in the workflow.